# Not able to handle exception in spring hibernate @transactional method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-transactions

I am not able to handle exception in DAO class method in case of `Transactional` annotation.

**Service Class method:**

```
 public String saveEmp(Employee emp) {
    return empDao.saveEmp(emp);
 }
```

**DAO Class method :**

```
   public String saveEmp(Employee emp) {
      try{
         return getHibernateTemplate.save(emp);
      }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException de){
         if(nameExist(emp)){
            throw new NameExistException();
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         throw new Exception(e.getstacktrace());
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your **service class** method like this

```
 @Transactional(readOnly=false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackfor={Throwable.class})
 public String saveEmp(Employee emp) {
    return empDao.saveEmp(emp);
 }
```

Now,if any exception occurs Spring framework will take care for rollback operation.I prefer to put the @Transactional annotation on service layer and not on DAO layer method.